# How to display a VLCj EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent on top of JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, vlcj

I was trying different libraries to play a video in my Java Swing game, I decided to use **VLCj**, I have a class called **CutscenePlayer** which is responsible for playing the videos but I also have a **JPanel** class called **GamePanel** and another class called **CutsceneManager** that calls the **CutscenePlayer**, whenever the video plays I can hear the sound but there's just a black screen, this is my **CutscenePlayer** class:

```java
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;

public class CutscenePlayer extends MediaPlayerEventAdapter {
    
    GamePanel gp;
    public static EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
    public boolean playing;
    public String video;
    
    public CutscenePlayer(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }
    
    public void setCutscene(String filePath) {
        video = filePath;
    }
    public void playCutscene() {
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        
        Main.window.add(mediaPlayerComponent);
        
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                    gp.gameState = gp.cutsceneState;
                    playing = false;
                }
            }
        );
        
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play(video);
    }
    public void play() {
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().pause();
    }
    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().pause();
    }
}
```

Here is the **CutsceneManager** code that calls the **CutscenePlayer**:

```java
if (isCutscenePlaying == false) {
    gp.csPlayer.setCutscene("test3.mp4");
    gp.csPlayer.playCutscene();
    isCutscenePlaying = true;
    gp.gameState = gp.cutscenePlayingState;
}
else {
    scenePhase++;
    isCutscenePlaying = false;
}
```

And here is the **GamePanel** code that has the thread and draws everything:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
final double drawInterval = 1000000000 / FPS;
        double delta = 0.0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        
        while (gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            while (delta >= 1.0) {
                if (gameState != cutscenePlayingState) {
                    update();
                    drawToTempScreen();
                    drawToScreen();
                }
                --delta;
            }
        }
    }
    public void update() {
        if (gameState == playState) {
            //PLAYER
            player.update();
            //NPC
            for (int i = 0; i < npc[1].length; i++) {
                if (npc[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    npc[currentMap][i].update();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < monster[1].length; i++) {
                if (monster[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    if (monster[currentMap][i].alive == true && monster[currentMap][i].dying == false) {
                        monster[currentMap][i].update();
                    }
                    if (monster[currentMap][i].alive == false) {
                        monster[currentMap][i].checkDrop();
                        monster[currentMap][i] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < projectile[1].length; i++) {
                if (projectile[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    if (projectile[currentMap][i].alive == true) {
                        projectile[currentMap][i].update();
                    }
                    if (projectile[currentMap][i].alive == false) {
                        projectile[currentMap][i] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < particleList.size(); i++) {
                if (particleList.get(i) != null) {
                    if (particleList.get(i).alive == true) {
                        particleList.get(i).update();
                    }
                    if (particleList.get(i).alive == false) {
                        particleList.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < iTile[1].length; i++) {
                if (iTile[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    iTile[currentMap][i].update();
                }
            }
            eManager.update();
        }
        if (gameState == pauseState) {
            //nothing
        }
    }
    public void drawToTempScreen() {
        //DEBUG
        long drawStart = 0;
        if (keyH.debugOn == true) {
            drawStart = System.nanoTime();
        }
        
        //TITLE SCREEN
        if (gameState == titleState) {
            ui.draw(g2);
        }
//      //MAP SCREEN
//      else if (gameState == mapState){
//          map.drawFullMapScreen(g2);
//      }
        //OTHERS
        else {
            //TILE
            tileM.draw(g2);
            
            //INTERACTIVE TILE
            for (int i = 0; i < iTile[1].length; i++) {
                if (iTile[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    iTile[currentMap][i].draw(g2);
                }
            }
            
            //ADD ENTITIES TO THE LIST
            entityList.add(player);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < npc[1].length; i++) {
                if (npc[currentMap][i] != null ) {
                    entityList.add(npc[currentMap][i]);
                }
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < obj[1].length; i++ ) {
                if (obj[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    entityList.add(obj[currentMap][i]);
                }
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < monster[1].length; i++ ) {
                if (monster[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    entityList.add(monster[currentMap][i]);
                }
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < projectile[1].length; i++ ) {
                if (projectile[currentMap][i] != null) {
                    entityList.add(projectile[currentMap][i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < particleList.size(); i++ ) {
                if (particleList.get(i) != null) {
                    entityList.add(particleList.get(i));
                }
            }
            //SORT
            Collections.sort(entityList, new Comparator<Entity>() {
                
                @Override
                public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
                    int result = Integer.compare(e1.worldY, e2.worldY);
                    return result;
                }
            });
            
            //DRAW ENTITIES
            for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
                entityList.get(i).draw(g2);;
            }
            //EMPTY ENTITY LIST
            entityList.clear();
            
            //ENVIORNMENT
            eManager.draw(g2);
            
//          //MINIMAP
//          map.drawMinimap(g2);
            
            //CUTSCENE MANAGER
            csManager.draw(g2);
            
            //UI
            ui.draw(g2);
            
            //TIME AMULET SCREEN
            if (gameState == timeAmuletState){
                g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
                dClock.drawClock(g2);
            }
            
        }
        
        //DEBUG
        if (keyH.debugOn == true) {
            long drawEnd = System.nanoTime();
            long passed = drawEnd - drawStart;
            System.out.println("Draw Time: " + passed);
            
            g2.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(20F));
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            int x = 10;
            int y = 400;
            int lineHeight = 20;
            
            g2.drawString("Draw Time: " + passed, x, y); y += lineHeight;
            g2.drawString("Col: " + (player.worldX + player.solidArea.x)/tileSize, x, y); y += lineHeight;
            g2.drawString("Row: " + (player.worldY + player.solidArea.y)/tileSize, x, y); y += lineHeight;
            g2.drawString("God Mode: "+ keyH.godModeOn, x, y); //y += lineHeight;
        }
    }
    public void drawToScreen() {
        if (gameState != cutscenePlayingState) {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(tempScreen, 0, 0, screenWidth2, screenHeight2, null);
            g.dispose();
        }
    }
```

And lastly, the **Main** class:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Time Maze");
        new Main().setIcon();
        
        window.add(gamePanel);

        gamePanel.config.loadConfig();
        if (gamePanel.fullScreenOn) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
        }

        window.pack();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        gamePanel.setUpGame();
        gamePanel.startGameThread();
}
```

I wanted it to play the video and then resume to the **GamePanel** so that the game can be continued, but instead I get a black screen (the color of the **GamePanel** background), and the game won't even resume. The problem is that the **GamePanel** is displayed over the *mediaPlayerComponent*. I tried setContentPane on the *mediaPlayerComponent* but after the video finishes the screen will be stuck on the last frame of the video.

Comment: Do you need to overlay your game panel on top of the video, or do you just need to be able to switch between the video and your game?

Comment: @caprica I just need to make the video play on top of the gamepanel, I can also switch between them. I tried using setVisible(false) on the gamepanel but after the video finishes the gamepanel won't appear and I'll be stuck on the last frame of the video.

Comment: Not quite enough for an answer, but what I suggest is using a CardLayout, have one card with the video, the other card with your game panel, and then you switch between them. This is what I do in the vlcj-player demo project which you can find at GitHub.

Comment: @caprica I fixed the issue a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the playCutscene() method with this:

```
public void playCutscene() {
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    Main.window.add(mediaPlayerComponent);
    Main.gamePanel.setVisible(false);
    playing = true;
    
    mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                Main.window.remove(mediaPlayerComponent);
                Main.gamePanel.setVisible(true);
                gp.gameState = gp.cutsceneState;
                playing = false;

                //mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            }
        }
    );
    //RELEASE RESOURCES ONLY WHEN EXITING APPLICATION,
    //OTHERWISE THERE'S A CHANCE OF PROGRAM TERMINATING
    mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play(video);
}
```

It works by adding the *mediaPlayerComponent* to the window and then setting the **GamePanel** to not visible. At the end of the video it sets it back to normal and releases the resources.

Comment: Just a note of caution, it is usually strongly recommended to reuse media player components rather than release them. There is a small but real chance of a native library crash when invoking release, and this will terminate your entire application. So if you can, keep your media player component around and reuse it instead of releasing it.

Comment: I realized that and fixed it, I added a WindowAdapter on window closing and then it releases the resources.